# Bash one liner to list all occupied IPs in a CIDR?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I need a Bash one liner that can print all occupied IPs in a CIDR that I give it, and I did not manage to find how to do it. I have a script that can perform this, but I did not manage to get it to run as a one liner. The script:

```
#!/bin/sh
pingf(){
    if ping -w 2 -q -c 1 10.5.99."$1" > /dev/null ;
    then 
        printf "IP %s is up\n" 10.5.99."$1"
    fi
}

main(){

    NUM=1
    while [ $NUM -lt 255  ];do 
        pingf "$NUM" &
        NUM=$(expr "$NUM" + 1)
    done
    wait
}
main
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: How about using `nmap`?

Comment: "nmap" is a package that does not exist in all Linux distributions by default, I am looking for something that will just work

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow's goal is to be a comprehensive knowledgebase of answers to *practical*, answerable questions. Focusing on building a one-liner over robust, readable and maintainable code is generally impractical (and the answer you accepted is made less readable by dubious "virtue" of compressing its code onto only two lines than it was in its original form).

Comment: @AdiVizgan : You can always squeeze a whole bash script into a single line. Just use `;` as a statement separator.

Comment: @AdiVizgan : BTW, you have tagged the question _bash_, but your #! line says it is a sh-script. If you really would turn it into a bash-script, you could write the increment of `NUM` easier as `((NUM++))`, and your while-condition could become `while ((NUM<255))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop with a sequence expression.

Replace the `if` statement with `&&` to combine the `ping` and `printf`.

```
for ip in 10.5.99.{1..255}; do ping -w 2 -q -c 1 "$ip" >/dev/null && printf "IP %s is up\n" "$ip" & done
wait
```

Sequence expressions are a `bash` extension, so you'll need to change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`.

Note that this just tests a single /24, not an arbitrary CIDR block. I can't think of a way to generalize this to CIDR blocks in a one-liner.

Comment: I tried this and wrote this command:
for i in {1..255}; do pingf 10.0.2.$i; done
but it says that pingf is not found. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you define the function first?

Comment: `pingf` is the function you defined at the top of your script.

Comment: I've merged the body of the function into the one-liner.

Comment: Yes! This worked! I just removed the "&" sign an the end before the ";" that broke it and it worked. Thanks a lot!
This is the result:
for ip in 10.0.2.{1..255}; do ping -w 2 -q -c 1 "$ip" >/dev/null && printf "IP %s is up\n" "$ip" ; done

Comment: You should remove the `;` not the `&`. You need `&` so it tests all the IPs in parallel instead of sequentially.